# Wireshark Google Analytics in native apps

Tags: google-analytics, wireshark

I have installed wireshark to sniff packets send from an ipad. It is on a shared network which my machine initiated and it uses this same machine as a http proxy.
So I tested in safari to open a site with google analytics on it, and with the following filter in wireshark I can see the http connection:
http.request.full_uri contains "UA-37906738-2"

I see all the connections made on the ipad. However, if I'm not in safari but in an app, this won't work. The data is defenetly send to google analytics, it is showing up in reports. In wireshark I'm not able see the connections made.

It's like the connection made with analytics SDK is not HTTP, but something different. Anyone has a clue on it?

I searched google for 30 minutes and everything and can't find any other community to answer this question. So anyone, please?

Comment: You near answered your question. Use the "sniffer" machine like a gateway so all the traffic pass thought it not only HTTP, then you can research that yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a bit. However i still not realy that much an expert in protocols. HTTP is easy to find in wireshark. But what else could i search for in wireshark? Can i filter the traffic, produced by the ipad or sthg?

Comment: Ofcourse, you have so much filter options in Wireshark, you can filter simple by the IP of the ipad for example. But if you don't pass the traffic troughs the computer that would not help. Maybe in promiscuous mode. If you want to do that you need a more study on networking and some Wireshark tutorials.